# A discount program code is missing from my programming code

Tags: java

I think a code is missing or not working because there should be a discount if the number is more than 5. For example a novel is borrowed for 6 days and so the rental charge should 8250. But isn't working as the rental charge is 9000.

Here is my program code:

```
**import java.util.Scanner;
class BookRentalShop 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of data you want to see: ");
        int inputnum = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        String[] Name = new String[inputnum];
        String[] Bookname = new String[inputnum];
        String[] AuthorName = new String[inputnum];
        String[] Booktype = new String[inputnum];
        int[] NumbersofDaysBorrowed = new int[inputnum];
        int[] RentalCharges = new int[inputnum];
        String[] Types = {"Cartoon","Magazine", "Short story", "Long story", "Journal", "Novel", "Encyclopedia"};
        int[] count = new int[7];


   for (int d = 0; d < inputnum; d = d + 1) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the person:");
        Name[d] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the bookname:");
        Bookname[d] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the author's name:");
        AuthorName[d] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the book type:");
        Booktype[d] = sc.nextLine();
        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
        {
            if (Booktype[d].equals(Types[k]))
            {
                count[k]++; 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the number of days that the book had been borrowed:");
        NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Cartoon")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 500;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Magazine")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 1000;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Short story")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 500;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Long story")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 1500;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Journal")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 350;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Novel")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 1500;
        } else {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 2500;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("%s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s\n", "No", "Name", "Bookname", "AuthorName", "Booktype", "Numbers of Days Borrowed", "Rental Charges");
    for (int d = 0; d < inputnum; d = d + 1) 
    {
        int num = d + 1;
        System.out.printf("%s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20d %20d\n", num, Name[d], Bookname[d], AuthorName[d], Booktype[d], NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d], RentalCharges[d]);
    }
    String again = "Yes";
    String exist = "No";
    while (again.equals("Yes")) {
        exist = "No";
        System.out.println("enter search name");
        String searchname = sc.nextLine();
        for (int d = 0; d < inputnum; d = d + 1) {
            if (searchname.equals(Name[d])) {
                System.out.println("Name           : " + Name[d]);
                System.out.println("Bookname       : " + Bookname[d]);
                System.out.println("Number of Days : " + NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d]);
                exist = "Yes";
            }
        }
        if (exist.equals("No")) {
            System.out.println("The search name is not found");
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to search again? (Yes,No) ");
        again = sc.nextLine();
    }
    int max = count[0];
    for (int d = 0; d < 7; d = d + 1)
    {
        for (int k =  d + 1; k < 7; k = k + 1)
        {
            if (count[k] > count[d]) 
            {
                max = count[k];
            }
            else {
                max = count[d];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The most rented book is: " + max);
    System.out.println("");
  }
}
```

Outcome of the program:

```
 No                 Name             Bookname           AuthorName             Booktype Numbers of Days Borrowed       Rental Charges
    1               ghjghj              hjghjgh                hfghg              Journal                    3                 1050
    2           hghjhgjhgj           uyiuyjghjg           ghytghghjg                Novel                    6                 9000
    3               bcvnvn              dasdasd               weqwew              Cartoon                    5                 2500*
```

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me find this problem.

Comment: I cannot find anything in your code that says there should be a discount if number is more than 5. Discount should be where number of days is more than 5 or numbers of books borrowed ?

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: It just prints number of days multiply by the cost of borrow.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong I am still a beginner in Java program so i don't know what the debugger is.

Comment: The debugger is one of the best ways to learn how code works. All of the major IDE’s (Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans, etc.) have debuggers where you can run code line by line, and see the state of your variables, what methods are being called. Time spent now learning to use it will benefit you greatly. It’s what we would use to troubleshoot your code which means you can cut out the middle person and get an answer faster.

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. The single most important skill you will ever learn is how to debug your own code. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Make sure you follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable anf method names alsays start with lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest solution like below:

This is the fragment of your code:

```
        System.out.println("Enter the number of days that the book had been borrowed:");
        NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Cartoon")) {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 500;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Magazine")) {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 1000;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Short story")) {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 500;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Long story")) {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 1500;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Journal")) {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 350;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Novel")) {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 1500;
        } else {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 2500;
        }
```

And under this code try to add this. It replace in array calculated cost of book reduced by discount which is e.g 750 when number of days is more than 5. You can change it like you want

```
            if(NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] > 5)
            {
                int bookCost = RentalCharges[d] / NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d];
                RentalCharges[d] = (5 * bookCost) + ((NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] - 5) * (bookCost / 2)); // DISCOUNT
            }
```

Comment: I tried the code you added with the Novel booktype and with 6 days borrowed and it worked but when i tried with another booktype like Magazine with 7 days borrowed, the rental charge is 16750. But the rental charge actual outcome should be 6000  of the Magazine with 7 days borrowed.

Comment: Its only example discount because I dont know actually how high it is. You have to calculate it. I just give you an example how to solve your problem

Comment: for example for Novel it is 6 * 1500 = 9000 and if i did 5 * 1500 = 7500 if it isn't more than 5 days but since it is 6 days, 1*1500 = 1500 divided by 2 or 50% which is 750. And so if it is 6 days then its 7500 + 750 = 8250. So how can 1500 divided by 50% or 2 be written in a code?

Comment: Every day after 5th one has 50% discount ?

Comment: I have replaced solution in my post. Try this one. It works for examples when after 5th day every day has 50% discount

Comment: I tried the solution you give and it works. Thank you very much for helping me with the problem and I appreciate it a lot.